# fill a textbox in a website using C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I want to fill a textbox in a website and click the submit button using C#

How can I do it ?

Html textbox code:

```
<input id="url" class="span8" type="text" placeholder="http://" name="url"></input>
```

Html button code:

```
<button id="preview" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="preview" type="submit" value="1"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></i> Upload</button>
```

Comment: What are you doing this from? A desktop application (WPF, Console, or Win Forms) or ASP.NET (MVC or Web Forms). Please realize that you must give more detail because we are not familiar with your application.

Comment: You can't click a html input box using C#, unless you are talking about a web driver framework like Selenium? You'll have to expand your question a bit I'm afraid.

Comment: @samjudson He needs more detail here, I doubt he's talking about automating the click of a button, I'd guess he's talking about the user clicking the button.

Comment: @mason I using Windows form and just want to fill a textbox in this address : http://www.newocr.com/ and submit it

Comment: @samjudson As I said I want only fill the the URL textbox in this address : http://www.newocr.com/ and submit the form using C#

Comment: I don't think a windows form will support html tags. Are you using Web Forms?

Comment: You'll want to POST data to the server, rather than actually filling out the form. See [How To Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [Post to remote URL, read response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114607/post-to-remote-url-read-response). I particularly like the answer on that was that wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the

```
runat="server"
```

in your input, and see if you can call it in the codebehind. If this doesn't work change it by some control that C# can understand.

Anyway, your button should look like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Save" CssClass="someCSSClass" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: He's not using ASP.NET. It's a Windows Forms application, the form appears to reside on a server and he wants to programmatically submit it.