# Post to remote URL, read response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have searched and found many different ways to post form data to a remote URL (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062078/response-redirect-which-posts-data-to-another-url-in-asp-net/6062248#6062248), etc.). What I cant seem to find is a way to do this AND parse the response from the remote server, in my case basic HTML to parse. Just to be clear I dont need help with parsing the data, I dont know how to get the response in a way I can then use. Is this possible, using httpresponse, or some other method? I seem to recall doing similar years ago, but only in a past life, and then, only in legend. Please advise and thanx in advance.

Sample response from server:

```
<H1>FormResponse</H1><BR>
<CENTER><B><I>Transaction was successful!</I></B></CENTER><BR>
<B>Transaction ID: </B>TP1H5X06T9RT5T<BR><B>Post Status: </B>Queued<BR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is use `WebRequest` or `HttpWebRequest`

I suggest you start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To clarify, the link you posted is not what you're looking for. That's for when your code IS the web request and you're writing a response to the client. What you're looking for is to be the client and to send a request and receive a response.

Comment: Thats EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanx! (stupid BRAIN, why didnt YOU remember that?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and its [UploadValues()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection()
     {
         { "foo", "bar"}
     };

     byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("http://www.google.com", nvc);
     string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);
}
```

Comment: looks interesting, will have to try it!